# How to fix "Unauthorized" error message from Twitterizer?

Tags: c#, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterizer, unauthorized

I downloaded the latest version of [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) and
I have the below code which tries to send an update a tweet to the twitter but it fails with "Unauthorized" Response status.

What could be the reason?

The keys were working before, why is it giving the below message and how to fix it?

[image]

And in my config I have this:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy/>
      <bypasslist/>
      <module/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the Access Tokens had expired oddly and created a simple page to regenerate the access tokens by Authorizing a Twitter Application (Consumer Tokens) to be able to send tweets to a Twitter User Account (Access Tokens):

[image]